# SQL Server 2019 user is dropped from database but error log says couldn't remove

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-administration

I have SQL Server 2019.

I have dropped a user from the database but there was below message in error log.

> "Couldn't remove the user (n) from database (n) from the external libraries folder, error: 0x80070003"

Dropped the user. Checked error log, the same issue appears again and again.

I have not seen this earlier. Appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have not seen that specific error but I had similar issue trying to drop a user that was owner of a DB or owner of some other object.  You would have to change ownership first before you can drop, in my case anyway.

Comment: Brad, thanks for the answer. My issue is user is successfully dropped from the db, but just a message in error log. Will try the ownership part though.

Comment: Not a SQL Server error message `SELECT *  FROM sys.messages  WHERE text LIKE '%external libraries%'`

Comment: Martin, no result for this query.

Comment: yes, So the error message isn't a SQL Server error message

Comment: I checked the external libraries but couldn't find any. May not be SQL but error message is logged in sql error log.

Comment: Look for a custom DDL trigger

Comment: No triggers are created on the database.